# Details of the proxy address which is being used by Mac

Tags: terminal, proxy

Is it possible to get the proxy address that my system is currently using in order to populate **HTTP_PROXY** variable from command line ?

I would like a command so that I could set it in my *.bashrc* file.

complete solution for me was to update my ***.bashrc*** file with this

```
function http_proxy { 
    export http_proxy=`networksetup -getwebproxy Wi-Fi  | head -3 | tail -2  | cut -f2 -d' ' | sed 'N;s/\n/:/'|grep -v ':0'`
}
alias homen="networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi '' ;http_proxy"
alias ofcn="networksetup -setwebproxy Wi-Fi proxy.examp.com 8080;http_proxy"
http_proxy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either get [ProxyConf](http://delx.net.au/projects/proxyconf/), which does exactly this.

Or retrieve the web proxy with `networksetup -getwebproxy Ethernet` (replace **Ethernet** with the one you're using from `networksetup -listallnetworkservices`), then format the output into HTTP_PROXY format:

```
$ networksetup -getwebproxy Ethernet | awk '/Server:/ {host=$2} /Port: / {port=$2} END { printf "http://%s:%s", host, port}'
http://127.0.0.1:8228
```

If your network services (Ethernet, Wifi, etc.) vary or you use multiple at the same time, you may need to get a little more elaborate to figure out which one is being used. `man networksetup` and `man ifconfig` should have everything you need if you want to go there.

Formerly there was also `scselect`, but `networksetup` incorporates all of it's functionality.

Comment: Updated question with the approach I took. Thanks Ingmar !